# When is the sum of 2019 positive integers greater than their product?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Al least, how many numbers are equal to 1?
I think I have the answer but I can't really proof this. Can someone help? 
Edit:
I'm sorry, yes , they are integers,
 What I have done so far:
I have "guessed" that they should be at least 2009 1's, because when minimizing all the numbers ( setting them equal to 2), then we see 22+2009 > 1024, but I can't really say why it is impossible  when you have 2008 1's or less

Comment: Are the numbers integer?

Comment: Well, if all the numbers are 1, then their product is less than their sum, for example.

Comment: For the other direction, see this [MO-question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/16684/when-is-the-product-of-a-set-of-numbers-greater-than-the-sum-of-them). For equality see [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3219187?seq=1). What is your answer, by the way? Or don't you have one after all.

Comment: It would help if you added what you have done so far, even if incomplete.

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin edit

Comment: @martycohen edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the tag of elementary number theory, I'm assuming you're working with integers. Otherwise, you can find $2019 ( 1 + \epsilon) > (1+\epsilon) ^ {2019}$.

---

**Hint:** With $x_i \geq 1$, $f(x_1, x_2, \ldots , x_n ) = \sum x_i - \prod x_i $ is a decreasing function in each $x_i$.

So, if $n$ of these values are not 1, then

> We may decrease these $n$ values to 2, while the inequality still holds. The remaining $2019-n$ values are 1, which gives us $2019 + n > 2^n$, of which the largest integer solution is $10$.

Hence, at most 10 of these integers are $ > 1$.

Comment: "The largest integer solution is n"?